# Calling a JS & CSS mimifier when creating WAR archive with Grails

Tags: grails, yui-compressor

When using Grails, when creating the WAR archive, I would like to apply a filter to all Javascript & CSS files : the yui-compressor mimifier. Is there a nice ways to achieve that with Grails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is answered, but if you do want to do it yourself, without installing plugins, look at:

http://www.milan-ramaiya.com/2010/09/15/compressing-javascript-and-css-using-yui-compressor-during-grails-build/

This will do it only when the war is built, and also shows you how to make changes to the warred files.

Answer (score 3):

The [UiPerformance plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) supports minification using YUI compressor. I don't know whether it can be enabled only when running the `grails war` task, but it can be enabled/disabled on a per-environment basis.

If you really want the minification to happen only when creating the .war (and the plugin doesn't already support this), you should ask the plugin's author(s) to add this feature or do it yourself and send them a patch file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering ! Those limitations are fine for me :)

Comment: The plugin only works when building a war - it has to be disabled in dev mode since a war isn't built for `run-app` and all of the compression/minification/etc. is done when building the war.